# Setting referential tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

I have two tables (A and B) that need to be related. The A has a int column that will be the foreign key column related to B table's primary key of tinyint. When I setup the relationship using SMS, I got the following error. How do I set this relationship up without changing the data type? Is it possible to cast A.FKey to int?

> The following data type properties of column 'dbo.A.FKey' do not match
>   those of 'dbo.B.PKey'.
>   - Data type
>   - Length
>   - Precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatypes must be the same on a relationship.  I advise altering the datatype to match.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a computed column in master table which cast pk column so it matches detailed column definition.  Then add a unique constraint on this computes column.  Finally, add fk in details table that refers computed column. However, it's much easier to alter table and make columns involved in relationship one type